# How to skip next lines of execution when catch error is occurred in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In a function I am having several try - catch blocks like:

```
private void button1_click()
{
   try
   {
      // Lines of code
   }
   catch
   {
      // Lines of code
   }

   try
   {
      // Lines of code
   }
   catch
   {
      // Lines of code
   }
}
```

If any error occurs in `catch` block say 1st catch, I don't want the next lines of code to execute.

How do I skip the next try block statements on 1st catch error?

Comment: If you have multiple `try-catch` blocks, perhaps you may want to extract your method into smaller units of work. This might make it easier to determine if you want to continue flow of execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would nest them, like this:

```
try
{
    //lines of code

    try
    {
        //lines of code
    }
    catch
    {
        //lines of code
    }
}
catch
{
    //lines of code
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use `return` in your first catch block:

```
try
{
    //lines of code
}
catch
{
    //lines of code
    return;
}

try
{
    //lines of code
}
catch
{
    //lines of code
}
```

Note that you have to be a little more thoughtful with the latter approach because if you're doing that in a method that needs to release resources (which you would do in a `finally` block), then the return would not accommodate that.

Answer (score -1):

Create several simple methods, that perform a little work and put try-catch block in each method.

```
private void button_click(){
   Method1();
   Method2();
   // etc...
}

private void Method1(){
   try{ /**/ } catch { /**/ }
}

private void Method1(){
   try{ /**/ } catch { /**/ }
}
```

You can add return bool operation result.

Example: return true if method pass complete and false if throw exception.

```
private void button_click(){
   bool r = Method1();

   if (!r) return;

   r = Method2();

   if (!r) return;

   r = Method3();  

   // etc...
}

private bool Method1(){
   bool r = true;
   try{ /**/ } 
   catch { 
      /**/
      r = false;
   }
   return r;
}

private bool Method2(){
   bool r = true;
   try{ /**/ } 
   catch { 
      /**/
      r = false;
   }
   return r;
}
```

Comment: That won't prevent `Method2()` from running when an exception is thrown in `Method1()`.

Comment: So I wrote following: 
> You can add return bool operation result.